# Take variable result and decrement by 1 in python

Tags: csv, dictionary, ip-address

This has got to be a real easy question and answer.  I have a dictionary key where the first usable IP address will always be the data.  I want to change it to the network IP so I just need to subtract 1 from the number.  Tried creating variable out of it that I can work with but I can't do math with strings.  Bonus points if I can decrement the IP without splitting it.  Can anyone point me int he right direction?

```py
import csv

minus_one = []

with open('iplist.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:

        ip = row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]
        split_ip = row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"].split(".")
        print(ip)
        print(split_ip)
        print('\n')

        if "172" in row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"].split(".")[0]:

            minus_one.append(
                f'{row["IP_ADDRESS_ZLOC"]} MINUS ONE???'
            )

print('\n'.join(minus_one))
```

output:

```
172.22.11.22
['172', '22', '11', '22']


172.22.11.33
['172', '22', '11', '33']


10.10.10.11
['10', '10', '10', '11']


172.22.11.22
['172', '22', '11', '22']


172.22.11.22 MINUS ONE???
172.22.11.33 MINUS ONE???
172.22.11.22 MINUS ONE???
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you meant:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    if row[:3] == "127":
        minus_one.append(
            '.'.join([str(int(x)+1)for i, x in enumerate(row.split('.')) if i 3 else x])
        )
```

Result:

```
172.22.11.23
172.22.11.34
172.22.11.23
```